# Execute GRASS modules in bash or python

Tags: python, grass-gis, linux, bash

I am a novice in writing scripts.

I have a line geometry. Let's say `line.shp`.
I want to smooth it with `v.generalize`, e.g.

```
v.generalize input=line output=line_chaiken method=chaiken \
threshold=1 error=roads_chaiken_leftover
```

What do I have to do to get the things done? Do I somehow have to do in three steps, like

- Load into GRASS
- v.generalize
- Write output

How would these steps fit into a script?

Answer (score 5):

In bash, you could do something like the following. I don't have your shapefile so I can't test that these are the exact commands that will work, but the approximate workflow may help you.

```
# create the region based on the shapefile, and execute script w/ commands
grass70 -c ./line.shp MyMap --exec sh script.sh
# the line above creates MyMap region (and folder on disk).
# to access it in the future, you would launch grass like this:
# grass70 ./MyMap/PERMANENT
```

In a separate script (named script.sh, with executable bit set) put whatever commands you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

# load the shapefile
v.in.ogr input=line.shp output=line
# smooth
v.generalize input=line output=line_chaiken method=chaiken
# write output
v.out.ogr input=line_chaiken output=line_chaiken.shp
```

See https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/grass7.html#batch-jobs-with-the-exec-interface (and comment from @markusN)

Comment: Thanks. Will try it at home. And if I not need the region and the folder after excecuting the processing; would it be possible to tell GRASS to delete them (within the script)?

Comment: To simplify even more, you can put all this into a script and run from the grass72 start script as a batch job, see: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/grass7.html#batch-jobs-with-the-exec-interface

Answer (score 2):

I ran your command and it needs more parameters. However, in your Linux system, you don't need to load the layer into GRASS. Assuming that a dataset has been created, first, you have to prepare your system to run adequately the script.

I have in my **.bashrc** the following lines (in this case for GRASS 6):

```
export GISBASE="/usr/lib/grass64"
export PATH="$PATH:$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/script:$GISBASE/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib"
export GIS_LOCK=$$
export GISRC="$HOME/.grassrc6"
```

In my home user, I created a new version of your script (by using a lot of parameters with **chaiken algorithm**; where my input line was **route** and my output line **test**).

```
v.generalize input=route layer=1 type=line -c type=line method=chaiken threshold=1.0 look_ahead=7 reduction=50 slide=0.5 angle_thresh=3 degree_thresh=0 closeness_thresh=0 betweeness_thresh=0 alpha=1.0 beta=1.0 iterations=1 output=test
```

For doing executable your script you need:

```
chmod +x script_name
```

and for running it:

```
./script_name
```

Finally, I have a **.grassrc6** file with next lines:

```
GISDBASE: /home/zeito/datagrass
LOCATION_NAME: utah
MAPSET: jose
GRASS_GUI: wxpython
```

After running the script at the bash console, resulting layer could be visualized at Map Canvas of QGIS:

[image]

It worked.

Comment: How does you bash script look like now? The parameters given for the algorithm derived from your personal experience? Do I have to make .bashrc and .grassrc6 look like yours? Maybe GRASS7 works like suggested by mankoff?

Comment: No, it won't work (mankoff suggestion has an exactly copy of your command ) because I tried out your script in my system and it didn't.  I have Debian stable and I should compile GRASS 7 in my system. For this reason, you only have to adapt my GRASS 6 suggestion to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Mint18 (Ubuntu 16.04) and it seems not to be possible to install a GRASS 6 on it. Could you also provide a GRASS 7 solution, please?

Comment: ... GRASS GIS 7 is much recommended over GRASS 6 anyway (faster, more reliable, more features etc etc).