# buffer raster in gdal

Tags: gdal

I am trying to do a simple buffer over a raster in gdal. My raster has values 1, NA (converted the 0 to NA). I am struggling to find a way to do this straight in gdal. Is there no such option for rasters?

Comment: What do you mean by "simple buffer over a raster"?

Comment: like this https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.buffer.html

Comment: GDAL isn't a GIS library (though it has *some* GIS capabilities), it's more data input/output and it doesn't have the functionality you refer to. It can however be used to read raster data into a numpy array that could be passed to something like [`scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html)

Comment: GRASS does support command line use as well. Which might be an option: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223214/execute-grass-modules-in-bash-or-python